# javascript synchronize inputs with same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I need to synchronize all inputs with same name.
I don't know inputs names.

Example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="number" name="fields[340]" required="" value="">
<input type="text" placeholder="number" name="fields[340]" required="" value="">
```

So now I need to synchronize inputs values.

Problem is that I don't know input names. This is what I have so far.

```
var $inputs = $(":input");
$inputs.keyup(function() {
     $inputs.val($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `'input[name="' + this.name + '"]'` selector to get the inputs with same name.

```js
var $inputs = $(":input");
$inputs.on('input',function() {
  $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').val($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="number" name="fields[340]" required="" value="">
<input type="text" placeholder="number" name="fields[340]" required="" value="">
<br/>
<input type="text" placeholder="number" name="fields[341]" required="" value="">
<input type="text" placeholder="number" name="fields[341]" required="" value="">
```